# Bulk rename directories names

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu

Trying to use GPRename for rename some directories quickly but no success.

I have some directories named with artist names like "StevieRayVaughan" and i need rename it to "Stevie Ray Vaughan".

Is some way to make it happen in bash/regular expression? space before upper letters?

Thank you.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com and superuser.com are better places for a question like this.

Comment: Thanks for let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [`perl-rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) sometimes called `rename` - not to be confused with [`rename` from util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

This tool take a Perl expressions and renames accordingly:

```
perl-rename 's/(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])/ /g' *
```

The above will rename all files / directories in the current directory to add spaces before uppercase letters:

```
helloWorld -> hello World
John Doe   -> John Doe
```

[You can try the regex online](https://ideone.com/zISjEe)

Comment: Thanks man, output for: % perl-rename 's/(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])/ /g' * is  bash: fg: %: no such job but rename 's/(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])/ /g' * works.

Comment: The `%` was to indicate a prompt for you to enter: `perl-rename ...`